# How can I replace an element in my document.write with a variable name

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>
<body>
<script>

  document.write("y = &#177;"+'&radic;<span style="border-top:1px solid black">16-x<sup>2</sup></span>'+"<br>");
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a lot of these:

```
document.write("y = &#177;"+'&radic;<span style="border-top:1px solid black">16-x<sup>2</sup></span>'+"<br>");
```

The `16` part I would rather be my variable `radius2`, so that I can change the value for each write.

I've tried editing myself, but can't figure out how to add `+ radius2 +` into the center

Comment: where is radius2 declared?

Comment: I had one my code is much larger then this was just wondering basically how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your variable `var radius = 16;`

Now replace 16 with that variable like this:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var radius2 = 16;
            document.write("y = &#177;"+'&radic;<span style="border-top:1px solid black">' + radius2 + '-x<sup>2</sup></span>'+"<br>");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you can insert your variable by wrapping it in `${}` - this also avoids having to jump between using `"` and `'` inside your string so much

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      let radius2 = 16;
      document.write(`y = &#177;&radic;<span style="border-top:1px solid black">${radius2}-x<sup>2</sup></span><br>`);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```